# Cómo recorrer un Array de objetos, contar los valores que se repiten y almacenarlos en diferentes contadores

Tags: javascript, array, google-chart-api

Yo tengo un Array con objetos en los cuales hay datos repetidos y me gustaría saber cómo podría hacer un contador totalmente dinámico que me fuese almacenando el número de veces que se repite cada propiedad de los mismos.

Ejemplo:
contadorAgua: 2
contadorHuevos: 2

Pero tendría que ser totalmente dinámico ya que estoy intentando hacer esto para posteriormente introducir los datos en google charts.

¡un saludo!

```
    google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['table']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Teamname');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Number of resources');

  var datos = [{
    producto: 'Papitas',
    importeVenta: 1650.30
  }, {
    producto: 'Refresco',
    importeVenta: 6852.30
  }, {
    producto: 'Agua',
    importeVenta: 785.50
  }, {
    producto: 'Agua',
    importeVenta: 785.50
  },{
    producto: 'Pan',
    importeVenta: 3812.00
  }, {
    producto: 'Frijol',
    importeVenta: 3805.00
  }, {
    producto: 'Huevos',
    importeVenta: 2005.10
  },
  {
    producto: 'Huevos',
    importeVenta: 2005.10
  } ]

  var dataChart = []
    $.each(datos,function(i, v) {
    console.log(v.producto + ' ' +  v.importeVenta  + ' \n' );
    if(v.importeVenta){
      dataChart.push([v.producto, v.importeVenta ]);
      contador = contador +1;
    }else{
      dataChart.push([v.producto, v.importeVenta ]);
    }
    });

    data.addRows(dataChart);


  var dataGroup = google.visualization.data.group(
    data,
    [0],
    [{
      column: 1,
      type: 'number',
      label: data.getColumnLabel(1),
      aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum
    }]
  );

  var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('generarGraficoQuesoGafasVendidasPorModeloYColor'));
  table.draw(dataGroup, {showRowNumber: true, width: '100%', height: '100%'});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes guardarlos en un objeto `contadores` donde sus propiedades sean cada nombre de producto y los valores las veces que aparece repetido. Gracias a la propiedad `hasOwnProperty`, te aseguras que las propiedades no se sobreescribirán. Te adjunto un ejemplo de como implementarlo.

```js
var contadores = {};

var datos = [{
    producto: 'Papitas',
    importeVenta: 1650.30
  }, {
    producto: 'Refresco',
    importeVenta: 6852.30
  }, {
    producto: 'Agua',
    importeVenta: 785.50
  }, {
    producto: 'Agua',
    importeVenta: 785.50
  },{
    producto: 'Pan',
    importeVenta: 3812.00
  }, {
    producto: 'Frijol',
    importeVenta: 3805.00
  }, {
    producto: 'Huevos',
    importeVenta: 2005.10
  },
  {
    producto: 'Huevos',
    importeVenta: 2005.10
  } ]

for (var i=0; i<datos.length; i++) {
    if (!contadores.hasOwnProperty(datos[i].producto)) {
        contadores[datos[i].producto] = 0;
    }
    contadores[datos[i].producto]++;
}

console.log(contadores);
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Aún sigo intentándolo implementar jajaj, ¡un saludo!